# Using arrow keys in jquery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

If you have a jQuery dialog window such as [**this**](http://jsbin.com/gumekugozu), and lets say you have a vertical scrollbar (E.g to much text where container has a specific height).

In IE you can then use arrows up and down alongside page up and down
however in chrome / firefox you can't they just scroll the outside page.

Is there anyway to make the behave the same?

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an usability or accessibility issue with the modal dialog box.The best approach is to trap focus of the modal dialog i.e. tabbing should not move focus out of dialog box. And also put a tabindex=0 on ui-dialog-content so that div must get focus on tabbing and then you can use up and down arrow key to navigate  content of modal dialog.